# NFC host card emulation Android

Tags: android, nfc, payment, contactless-smartcard, hce

I read contradicting things about the possibility implementing NFC Tap & Pay  Android mobile app

I was successful in testing out this app - https://github.com/championswimmer/NFC-host-card-emulation-Android

Is it really possible to generate a tokenized card (say issued by VISA) and emulate a payment card and complete the transaction at a terminal ?

If so, Is there any protocol / spec for contactless card transmission ?

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: `ISO 14443`, `Java Card 3.0.4`, `GlobalPlatform`, `ISO 7816`